# how to get the api host in the frontend ? REACT/AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, base-url

```
const GetTask = async () => {

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/daily-tasks')

        dispatch({
            type: GET_TASK,
            payLoad: res.data
            
        })
```

so i need something like this  `const res = await axios.get('${baseURL}/daily-tasks')`

BASICLY  i need to hold the current localhost in the frontend only if possible,
so i could hold it and run dynamicly

thanks all

please help

Answer (score 1):

You can store that in a env file or set axios defaults in index file of app.

```
axios.defaults.baseURL="your endpoint"
```

Once you set this you can simply do

```
Axios.get("/posts")
```

You don't have to append baseurl anymore